# How to draw a revolving door with Asymptote?

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote

[image]

Here's a code example for a revolving door image I created with Ti*k*Z. How can I convert this code into code for asymptote?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections,shadings,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round, line join=round,x=2mm,y=2mm]
\tikzset{
CungElip/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{
insert path={+ (#1:#3) arc (#1:#2:#3)}
}
}
\definecolor{nauden}{RGB}{52,32,0}
\definecolor{vangxam}{RGB}{190,155,100}
\fill[cyan!30] (-9,-2)rectangle(9,16);
\clip (8,0) arc (0:-180:16mm and 3.2mm) -- (-8,14) arc (180:0:16mm and 3.2mm) --cycle;
\shade[bottom color=vangxam!50!white,top color=vangxam!50!black] (0,0) [CungElip=0:360:16mm and 3.2mm];
\shade[yshift=23.2mm,bottom color=black,top color=gray!70] (0,0) [CungElip=0:360:16mm and 3.2mm];
\begin{scope}[even odd rule, overlay]
\clip (8,11.6) arc (0:-50:16mm and 3.2mm)--++(0,-9.2) arc (50:0:16mm and 3.2mm)--cycle
($(8,11.6)+(0,-0.5)$) arc (3:-47:16mm and 3.2mm)--++($(0,-9.2)+(0,1)$) arc (47:-3:16mm and 3.2mm)--cycle;
\fill[gray!80] (8,11.6) arc (0:-60:16mm and 3.2mm)--++(0,-9.2) arc (60:0:16mm and 3.2mm)--cycle;
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[even odd rule, overlay]
\clip (-8,11.6) arc (-180:-130:16mm and 3.2mm)--++(0,-9.2) arc (130:180:16mm and 3.2mm)--cycle
($(-8,11.6)+(0,-0.5)$) arc (-177:-133:16mm and 3.2mm)--++($(0,-9.2)+(0,1)$) arc (133:177:16mm and 3.2mm)--cycle;
\fill[gray!80] (-8,11.6) arc (-180:-130:16mm and 3.2mm)--++(0,-9.2) arc (130:180:16mm and 3.2mm)--cycle;
\end{scope}
\fill[gray!50,opacity=0.3] ($(8,11.6)+(0,-0.5)$) arc (3:32:16mm and 3.2mm)--++($(0,-13.5)+(0,1.5)$) arc (-32:-3:16mm and 3.2mm)--cycle;
\fill[gray!50,opacity=0.3] ($(-8,11.6)+(0,-0.5)$) arc (177:148:16mm and 3.2mm)--++($(0,-13.5)+(0,1.5)$) arc (-148:-177:16mm and 3.2mm)--cycle;
\draw[gray!50,line width=1pt] (8,11.6) arc (0:35:16mm and 3.2mm)--++(0,-13.5) arc (-35:0:16mm and 3.2mm)--cycle;
\draw[gray!50,line width=1pt] (-8,11.6) arc (180:145:16mm and 3.2mm)--++(0,-13.5) arc (-145:-180:16mm and 3.2mm)--cycle;
\begin{scope}[even odd rule, overlay]
\clip (8,11.6) arc (0:35:16mm and 3.2mm)--++(0,-13.5) arc (-35:0:16mm and 3.2mm)--cycle
($(8,11.6)+(0,-0.5)$) arc (3:32:16mm and 3.2mm)--++($(0,-13.5)+(0,1.5)$) arc (-32:-3:16mm and 3.2mm)--cycle;
\fill[gray!50] (8,11.6) arc (0:35:16mm and 3.2mm)--++(0,-13.5) arc (-35:0:16mm and 3.2mm)--cycle;
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[even odd rule, overlay]
\clip (-8,11.6) arc (180:145:16mm and 3.2mm)--++(0,-13.5) arc (-145:-180:16mm and 3.2mm)--cycle
($(-8,11.6)+(0,-0.5)$) arc (177:148:16mm and 3.2mm)--++($(0,-13.5)+(0,1.5)$) arc (-148:-177:16mm and 3.2mm)--cycle;
\fill[gray!50] (-8,11.6) arc (180:145:16mm and 3.2mm)--++(0,-13.5) arc (-145:-180:16mm and 3.2mm)--cycle;
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[overlay]
\clip (8,11.6) arc (0:180:16mm and 3.2mm)--++(0,2.4) arc (180:0:16mm and 3.2mm)--++(0,-2.4)--cycle;
\shade[left color=white, right color=gray] (0,11)rectangle(8,17);
\shade[left color=gray, right color=white] (-8,11)rectangle(0,17);
\end{scope}
\coordinate (B) at ($(0,0)+(50:16mm and 3.2mm)$);
\coordinate (A) at ($(0,0)+(215:16mm and 3.2mm)$);
\coordinate (C) at ($(0,0)+(130:16mm and 3.2mm)$);
\coordinate (D) at ($(0,0)+(-35:16mm and 3.2mm)$);
\coordinate[yshift=23.2mm] (D1) at ($(0,0)+(35:16mm and 3.2mm)$);
\coordinate[yshift=23.2mm] (C1) at ($(0,0)+(-130:16mm and 3.2mm)$);
\coordinate[yshift=23.2mm] (B1) at ($(0,0)+(-50:16mm and 3.2mm)$);
\coordinate[yshift=23.2mm] (A1) at ($(0,0)+(-215:16mm and 3.2mm)$);
\path[name path=ab] (A)--(B); 
\path[name path=cd] (C)--(D);
\path[name path=a1b1] (A1)--(B1); 
\path[name path=c1d1] (C1)--(D1);
\path[name intersections={of=ab and cd,by=M}];
\path[name intersections={of=a1b1 and c1d1,by=N}];
\begin{scope}[even odd rule, overlay]
\clip (B)--(M)--(N)--(B1)--cycle ($(B)+(-.3,.6)$)--($(M)+(.3,.7)$)--($(N)+(.3,-.7)$)--($(B1)+(-.3,-.6)$)--cycle;
\fill[white] (B)--(M)--(N)--(B1)--cycle;
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[even odd rule, overlay]
\clip (C)--(M)--(N)--(C1)--cycle ($(C)+(.3,.6)$)--($(M)+(-.3,.7)$)--($(N)+(-.3,-.7)$)--($(C1)+(.3,-.6)$)--cycle;
\fill[white] (C)--(M)--(N)--(C1)--cycle;
\end{scope}
\fill[gray!50,opacity=0.3] (C)--(M)--(N)--(C1)--cycle ($(C)+(.3,.6)$)--($(M)+(-.3,.7)$)--($(N)+(-.3,-.7)$)--($(C1)+(.3,-.6)$)--cycle;
\fill[gray!50,opacity=0.3] (B)--(M)--(N)--(B1)--cycle ($(B)+(-.3,.6)$)--($(M)+(.3,.7)$)--($(N)+(.3,-.7)$)--($(B1)+(-.3,-.6)$)--cycle;

\draw[line width=.4pt,nauden] ($(B)+(-.3,.6)$)--($(M)+(.3,.7)$)--($(N)+(.3,-.7)$)--($(B1)+(-.3,-.6)$)--cycle;
\draw[line width=.4pt,nauden] ($(C)+(.3,.6)$)--($(M)+(-.3,.7)$)--($(N)+(-.3,-.7)$)--($(C1)+(.3,-.6)$)--cycle;
\draw[line width=1.2pt,nauden] (M)--(B)--(B1)--(N) (M)--(C)--(C1)--(N);
\begin{scope}[even odd rule, overlay]
\clip (D)--(M)--(N)--(D1)--cycle ($(D)+(-.45,.8)$)--($(M)+(.3,.7)$)--($(N)+(.3,-.7)$)--($(D1)+(-.45,-.8)$)--cycle;
\fill[white] (D)--(M)--(N)--(D1)--cycle;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[even odd rule, overlay]
\clip (A)--(M)--(N)--(A1)--cycle ($(A)+(.45,.8)$)--($(M)+(-.3,.7)$)--($(N)+(-.3,-.7)$)--($(A1)+(.45,-.8)$)--cycle;
\fill[white] (A)--(M)--(N)--(A1)--cycle;
\end{scope}
\fill[gray!50,opacity=0.3] ($(D)+(-.45,.8)$)--($(M)+(.3,.7)$)--($(N)+(.3,-.7)$)--($(D1)+(-.45,-.8)$)--cycle;
\fill[gray!50,opacity=0.3] ($(A)+(.45,.8)$)--($(M)+(-.3,.7)$)--($(N)+(-.3,-.7)$)--($(A1)+(.45,-.8)$)--cycle;
\draw[line width=.4pt,nauden] ($(D)+(-.45,.8)$)--($(M)+(.3,.7)$)--($(N)+(.3,-.7)$)--($(D1)+(-.45,-.8)$)--cycle;
\draw[line width=.4pt,nauden] ($(A)+(.45,.8)$)--($(M)+(-.3,.7)$)--($(N)+(-.3,-.7)$)--($(A1)+(.45,-.8)$)--cycle;
\draw[line width=1.2pt,nauden] (M)--($(A)+(.2,0)$)--($(A1)+(.2,0)$)--(N)--cycle (M)--($(D)+(-.2,0)$)--($(D1)+(-.2,0)$)--(N);
\draw[line width=1pt,gray,rounded corners=1.2pt] ($(M)!.45!(N)+(-.1,-.2)$)--($(C)!.45!(C1)+(.2,-.2)$)--++(120:.05mm) ($(M)!.45!(N)+(.1,-.2)$)--($(B)!.45!(B1)+(-.2,-.2)$)--++(60:.05mm);
\draw[line width=1pt,gray!60,rounded corners=1.2pt] ($(M)!.45!(N)+(-.1,-.2)$)--($(A)!.45!(A1)+(.5,-.2)$)--++(120:.2mm) ($(M)!.45!(N)+(.1,-.2)$)--($(D)!.45!(D1)+(-.5,-.2)$)--++(60:.2mm);
\fill[gray!50] (0,12.5) ellipse (.3mm and .15 mm);
\fill[white] (0,12.5) ellipse (.15mm and .075 mm);
\fill[black!50] (-.3,14.2)--(.3,14.2)--(.4,14.6)--(-.4,14.6)--cycle ;
\fill[red!50!gray] (0,14.4) circle (.3pt);
\draw[gray!30,line width=1pt] (6.5,-1.2)--(6.5,15.5) (-6.5,-1.2)--(-6.5,15.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This question is just like your bicycle question, except that now we have a door rather than a bicycle. Please note that the site is not intended to provide a showcase of examples - it really is for asking and answering questions. But you aren't asking questions at all and there doesn't seem to be anything you want help with. As suggested previously, [texample.net](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420495/code-example-on-how-to-draw-an-image-with-tikz-bicycle) might be a good place to submit your code.

Comment: @cfr I think that this question is different in that there is a real question: how to convert Ti*k*Z code into asymptote. In principle, that is a very interesting question, I think. However, in the case at hand, only 2D coordinates are used. On the other hand, I'd like to argue that it is a bit pointless to convert it into a 2D asymptote picture. Yet converting it to a 3D picture will essentially mean to start from scratch.

Comment: This is a really really nice picture, but I am wondering what you would like to achieve. IMHO the only thing that would make sense is to make a 3D asymptote picture. Yet in your code there are no 3D coordinates whatsoever. Unless you provide the 3D data, I guess there will be huge threshold for others trying to answer your question.

Comment: @marmot The other question also included the bit about asymptote. But is it a question? I took it to be a comment. ('!' and not '?') I was confused in both posts by the bit about asymptote - it doesn't seem to relate to anything and I can't think of any reason to convert it. (Especially since moving to 3D will mean moving to raster.)

Comment: @cfr I could think of a reason: you can then animate the whole thing rather easily (provided you write an appropriate asymptote code). And in principle it is much easier to write this in asymptote.

Comment: @marmot Easier the animation? Or easier the door? Presumably, the door is only easier if you don't have it in Ti*k*Z already, so I assume you mean the animation. I didn't know asymptote did animations, to be honest, so that's interesting to know. However, if that's what's wanted, this strikes me as way too large a question for this format. ;)

Comment: @cfr Yes, asymptote is rather impressive in this regard, see [here](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/animations/). And all the bulky shading in the above (of course very nice) Ti*k*Z picture is sort of automatic, the code for [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gkQW.png) is just a few lines.

Comment: Why is this even closed? You can ask a thousand questions about tikz to asymptote conversion. We have many Asymptote users.]

Comment: @marmot and why [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gkQW.png) is not animate? ;-)

Comment: @Tarass Because it is an animal;-)

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Sorry you! Bacause my English is bad, i want to learn 3D asym code for my door.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First of all, congratulations to your picture and also to your [bike](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420495/code-example-on-how-to-draw-an-image-with-tikz-bicycle). Here is an asymptote code that could be a starting point. I am obviously much less talented than you, but I will be happy to assist you with further features. Note that it is perhaps simplest to compile this with `pdflatex -shell-escape` or something similar since then asymptote will be automatically called. **UPDATE**: It turns out that the orientation of the boundary matters when filling a surface in asymptote, see page 78 of [this tutorial](https://math.uchicago.edu/~cstaats/Charles_Staats_III/Notes_and_papers_files/asymptote_tutorial.pdf). This explains the strange diagonal lines in my previous figure. In this update, I fixed this, and I also made the door a bit wider.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\def\myangle{45}
\begin{document}
\begin{asypicture}{name=AsyDoor}
import graph3;
import solids;

size(8cm,8cm);
settings.render = 4;
currentprojection = perspective((-3,20,1), up=Z,autoadjust=true);//,autoadjust=true
currentlight=(2,15,5);
int doorangle = 135;

real Rad=2; // that's not the "true" radius but some parameter controlling the width

picture fig;
size(fig,10cm);
// coordinate axes 
//draw(O -- 2X,L=Label("$x$",position=EndPoint));
//draw(O -- 2Y,L=Label("$y$", position=EndPoint));
//draw(-2Z -- 2Z,L=Label("$z$", position=EndPoint));
//
path3 uppercircle = circle(c=2Z, r=Rad*1.1*sqrt(2), normal=Z);
surface uppercylinder = extrude(uppercircle, 0.4Z);
draw(uppercylinder, surfacepen=blue);
//
path3 lowercircle = circle(c=-2Z, r=Rad*1.1*sqrt(2), normal=Z);
surface lowercylinder = extrude(lowercircle, 0.1Z);
draw(lowercylinder, surfacepen=blue);
//
path3 doorboundary =  Rad*sqrt(2)*X+2Z -- Rad*sqrt(2)*X-1.9*Z -- -1.9*Z -- 2*Z -- cycle;
surface door = surface(doorboundary);
//
material glassdoor = material(lightblue+opacity(0.3));
//
for (int ang=doorangle; ang<=doorangle+90;ang+=90)
{
draw(rotate(ang,Z)*door, glassdoor);
draw(rotate(ang,Z)*shift(-Rad*sqrt(2)*X)*door, glassdoor);
draw(rotate(ang,Z)*scale3(0.97)*doorboundary, p=lightgray+linewidth(3pt));
draw(rotate(ang,Z)*shift(-Rad*sqrt(2)*X)*scale3(0.97)*doorboundary, p=lightgray+linewidth(3pt));
draw(rotate(ang-90,Z)* (0.97*Rad*sqrt(2)*X-0.2*Z .. 
0.87*Rad*sqrt(2)*X-0.2*Z -0.1*Rad*sqrt(2)*Y 
-- 0.1*Rad*sqrt(2)*X-0.2*Z -0.1*Rad*sqrt(2)*Y .. 
-0.2*Z), p=lightgray+linewidth(5pt));
draw(rotate(ang+90,Z)* (0.97*Rad*sqrt(2)*X-0.2*Z .. 
0.87*Rad*sqrt(2)*X-0.2*Z -0.1*Rad*sqrt(2)*Y 
-- 0.1*Rad*sqrt(2)*X-0.2*Z -0.1*Rad*sqrt(2)*Y .. 
-0.2*Z), p=lightgray+linewidth(5pt));
}

//

// SURFACES
// left and right boundaries
triple S1(pair uv) {
  real x = 1.05*Rad*sqrt(2)*cos(uv.x);
  real y = 1.05*Rad*sqrt(2)*sin(uv.x);
  real z = uv.y;
  return (x, y, z);
}
// upper and lower
triple S2(pair uv) {
  real x = uv.y * 1.1* Rad*sqrt(2)*cos(uv.x);
  real y = uv.y * 1.1* Rad*sqrt(2)*sin(uv.x);
  real z =0;
  return (x, y, z);
}
//
for (int ang=135; ang<=315;ang+=180)
{
draw(rotate(ang,Z)*arc(c=1.95*Z, 1.05*Rad*sqrt(2)*X+1.95*Z, 1.05*Rad*sqrt(2)*Y+1.9*Z), p=gray+linewidth(4pt));
draw(rotate(ang,Z)*arc(c=-1.85*Z, 1.05*Rad*sqrt(2)*X-1.85*Z, 1.05*Rad*sqrt(2)*Y-1.85*Z), p=gray+linewidth(4pt));
draw(rotate(ang,Z)* (1.05*Rad*sqrt(2)*X+1.9*Z--1.05*Rad*sqrt(2)*X-1.85*Z), p=gray+linewidth(4pt));
draw(rotate(ang+90,Z)* (1.05*Rad*sqrt(2)*X+1.9*Z--1.05*Rad*sqrt(2)*X-1.85*Z), p=gray+linewidth(4pt));
}
//
surface leftboundary = surface(S1, (-pi/4, -2), (pi/4,2), 64, 64, Spline);
surface rightboundary = surface(S1, (pi-pi/4, -2), (pi+pi/4,2), 64, 64, Spline);
draw(leftboundary, surfacepen=material(diffusepen=gray(0.1)+opacity(0.5),emissivepen=gray(0.3),specularpen=gray(0.1)));
draw(rightboundary, surfacepen=material(diffusepen=gray(0.1)+opacity(0.5),emissivepen=gray(0.3),specularpen=gray(0.1)));
//
surface upperboundary = shift(2Z) *surface(S2, (0, 0), (2pi,1), 64, 64, Spline);
surface lowerboundary = shift(-1.9Z) *surface(S2, (0, 0), (2pi,1), 64, 64, Spline);
draw(upperboundary, surfacepen=material(diffusepen=gray(0.1),emissivepen=gray(0.3),specularpen=gray(0.1)));
draw(lowerboundary, surfacepen=material(diffusepen=yellow,emissivepen=gray(0.3),specularpen=gray(0.1)));
\end{asypicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And this can be made a truly revolving door.

[image]

**UPDATE**: I fixed the lengths of the door handles (I hope) and I am indebted to Charles Staats for [explaining me some features](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/421887/121799) of the asypictureB package. These allowed me to produce the animations more conveniently. (And without this package this answer would not exist anyway.) Ways to produce the animation are discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/421916/121799). (Currently, I find that the compilation time is shorter if I use [this chain](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/421887/121799), though, but most likely I am doing something stupid.)

Comment: Yes, it's worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry. :)