# Drawing parallelogram and circle in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I want to draw a Parallelogram
 which there is a line perpendicular to it and also there are some circles on this Parallelogram and some points on the circles. as you can see in this picture.
 could any body tell me how I can do that in latex?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Latex.SX. Try to provide a minimal compilable working example. Do circles look like circles or like ellipses for perspective vision ?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! what you try so far? for an similar picture? o you look to http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/

Comment: That will look uggly without perspective ...

Answer (score 7):

I am wondering about the same thing as @Tarass. Here are both possibilities, a picture according to your description and a 3D picture.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{110}{20}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 \subfloat{\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (-4,-2) -- (2,-2,0) -- (4,2,0) -- (-2,2,0) -- cycle;
 \draw (0,0) circle ({2/3});
 \draw (0,0) circle ({4/3});
 \foreach \Angle in {45,135,225,315}
 {\draw[fill] ({\Angle-30}:{2/3}) circle (1pt);
 \draw[fill] ({\Angle+15}:{4/3}) circle (1pt);}
 \draw (0,0) -- (0,3);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat{\begin{tikzpicture}
 \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{90}{0}{0}
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
 \draw (0,0,0) circle ({2/3});
 \draw (0,0,0) circle ({4/3});
 \foreach \Angle in {45,135,225,315}
 {\draw[fill] ({\Angle-45}:{2/3}) circle (1pt);
 \draw[fill] (\Angle:{4/3}) circle (1pt);}
 \draw (-2,-2,0) -- (2,-2,0) -- (2,2,0) -- (-2,2,0) -- cycle;
 \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You were faster ...

Comment: @Tarass No worries, I upvoted your post as well. ;-)

Comment: You had time to do this too !!!

Comment: @Tarass Not really, I am still busy with [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/421716/121799) and [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gkQW.png).

Comment: That shall never pass throught this !!

Comment: @Tarass Sorry, the language barrier. (I'll decouple now, have fun with the next questions ;-)

Comment: The bird never pass the door.

Comment: @Tarass I see ;-) I think it's just a matter of perspective ;-)

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x  = {(1cm,0cm)},
                    y  = {(40:.5cm)},
                    z  = {(0cm,1cm)}]
\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
  \draw (0,0) circle (3) ;
  \draw (0,0) circle (2) ;
  \draw (-5,-4) -- (5,-4) -- (5,4) -- (-5,4) -- cycle ;

  \foreach \x in {30,60,...,360} {\fill (\x:3) circle (2pt) ;} ;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
  \draw[-stealth] (0,0)--(0,4) ;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw (0,0) circle (1) ;
  \draw (0,0) circle (.5) ;

  \draw (-7,-2) -- (2.5,-2) -- (7,1.5) -- (-2.5,1.5) -- cycle ;
  \draw[-stealth] (0,0)--(0,4) ;
  \foreach \x in {30,60,...,360} {\fill (\x:1) circle (2pt) ;} ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```